# Why does a raft reduce / limit build volume?

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, build-plate, rafts

I am using Cura 4.13.1 as a slicer for my Ender 3 v2 printer.

I want to print a model which I scaled to 400 %. To improve bed adhesion I wanted to add a default raft (Extra Margin = 15 mm). Unfortunately, Cura is not able to slice the model despite being still within the printer's build volume (400 % = 190x200x200 mm). I have to reduce the scaling to 365 %  (= 171x183x180 mmm) to fit the slicing.

As a workaround for printing the 400 % size, I will try to use a small support structure for better bed adhesion but I would prefer a raft.

**Edit:** Sorry for leaving out the info about the models form. I get the 220+raft limitation but my model is tapered downwards:
[image]

So the raft actually fits the printers/slicers default limit.
Does it really not matter and cura simply adds the raft size to models max X and Y values?

Comment: 15 mm of raft margin should really not be needed. Reducing that might help it fit.

Answer (score 2):

The raft still needs to fit on the bed, and it counts as a print, because, it is printed. You want the raft for better adhesion, so that means that you need more contact with the bed. If you’re not, your basically wasting filament. Its kinda logical actually.

Comment: Thank you but I forget some info. See the edited question please.

Answer (score 1):

### Adjusted model Dimensions

The model has the size determined by the base area of the bounding box, in this case, $\pu{190 \times 200 mm }$. The raft as told by OP adds 15mm on **all** sides of the model, and thus adds 30 mm in total on both the X and Y dimensions. This gets us a bounding box floor area of $\pu{220 \times 230 mm}$.

The model's bounding box has a height of $\pu{200 mm}$. Add to that the thickness of the raft. This is not mentioned, but in the worst case, this is about 3 mm, and so you get $\pu{203 mm}$ as the maximum. Our model's Bounding Box thus is $\pu{220\times 230\times 203 mm}$

The smaller scale model ($\pu{171 \times 183 \times 180 mm}$) results in an adjusted area of $\pu{201 \times 213 \times 183 mm}$.

### Printer dimensions

The standard Creality Ender3 v2 is set up with a build volume of ($\pu{220\times 220\times 250 mm}$) As your base area is 230 mm in one dimension, it just can't fit. The slightly scaled item is *just* under that dimension and thus fits.

### Solutions

With a firmware update, the printer can be told to use all of the bed, and then Cura's printer settings can be adjusted accordingly.

Sometimes, but not in this case, rotating the model can result in a model that doesn't fit in normal orientation to fit: A line of 240 mm doesn't fit along the X or Y axis, but easily along the diagonal of the printer. In fact, it is enough to turn the model by about 23.3° and the line fits:

[image: Graphic showing a 240 mm line of 0.45 mm width first at horizontal orientation and then at a 23.3-degree angle fitting inside a gray box of 220 mm width]

Comment: What? Did Creality actually go and break the stock firmware to only allow 220 mm of motion?? The bed is 235 and I don't recall my original Ender 3 having any limits on use of the full build area in the stock firmware back then. Or is this just a bad Cura profile limiting it?

Comment: Thank you but I forget some info. See the edited question please.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE it is set to 220 in the firmware stock. It's however rather easy to change... if you want.